# Firebase function connection with GCP Redis instance in the same VPC keeps on disconnecting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-functions

I am working on multiple Firebase cloud functions (all hosted in the same region) that connect with a GCP hosted Redis instance in the same region, using a VPC connector. I am using version 3.0.2 of the nodejs library for Redis. In the cloud functions' debug logs, I am seeing frequent connection reset logs, triggered for each cloud function with no fixed pattern around the timeline for the connection reset. And each time, the error captured in the error event handler is ECONNRESET. While creating the Redis instance, I have provided a retry_strategy to reconnect after 5 ms with maximum of 10 such attempts, along with the retry_unfulfilled_commands set to true, expecting that any unfulfilled command at the time of connection reset will be automatically retried (refer the code below).

```
const redisLib = require('redis');
const client = redisLib.createClient(REDIS_PORT, REDIS_HOST, {
    enable_offline_queue: true,
    retry_unfulfilled_commands: true,
    retry_strategy: function(options) {
        if (options.error && options.error.code === "ECONNREFUSED") {
          // End reconnecting on a specific error and flush all commands with
          // a individual error
          return new Error("The server refused the connection");
        }

        if (options.attempt > REDIS_CONNECTION_RETRY_ATTEMPTS) {
          // End reconnecting with built in error
          console.log('Connection retry count exceeded 10');
          return undefined;
        }

        // reconnect after 5 ms
        console.log('Retrying connection after 5 ms');
        return 5;
      },
});

client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Redis instance connected');
});

client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(`Error connecting to Redis instance - ${err}`);
});

exports.getUserDataForId = (userId) => {
    console.log('getUserDataForId invoked');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(!client.connected) {
            console.log('Redis instance not yet connected');
        } 
        
        client.get(userId, (err, reply) => {
            if(err) {
                console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(reply);
            }
        });
    });
}

// more such exports for different operations
```

Following are the questions / issues I am facing.

1. Why is the connection getting reset intermittently?
2. I have seen logs that even if the cloud function is being executed, the connection to Redis server lost resulting in failure of the command.
3. With retry_unfulfilled_commands set to true, I hoped it will handle the scenario as mentioned in point number 2 above, but as per debug logs, the cloud function times out in such scenario. This is what I observed in the logs in that case.

```
getUserDataForId invoked
Retrying connection after 5 ms
Redis instance connected
Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout' --> coming from wrapper cloud function
```

4. Should I, instead of having a Redis connection instance at global level, try to have a connection created during each such Redis operation? It might have some performance issues as well as issues around number of concurrent Redis connections (since I have multiple cloud functions and all those will be creating Redis connections for each simultaneous invocation), right?

So, how to best handle it since I am facing all these issues during development itself, so not really sure if it's code related issue or some infrastructure configuration related issue.

Comment: Are you using Memorystore for Redis or is your Redis hosted on a GCE instance or GKE? Also could you share with us the Redis version you are using and a full log entry of the ECONNRESET error.

Comment: I am using Memorystore for Redis. Version is 4.0 (Basic Tier).
I don't see any other log in the cloud functions logs, except the error being logged as ECONNRESET. Is there a way to get enhanced Redis logging?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior could be caused by background activities.

> "Background activity is anything that happens after your function has
> terminated"

When the background activity interferes with subsequent invocations in Cloud Functions, unexpected behavior and errors that are hard to diagnose may occur. Accessing the network after a function terminates usually leads to ***"ECONNRESET"*** errors.

To troubleshoot this, make sure that there is no background activity by searching the logs for entries after the line saying that the invocation finished. Background activity can sometimes be buried deeper in the code, especially when asynchronous operations such as callbacks or timers are present. Review your code to make sure all asynchronous operations finish before you terminate the function.

[Source](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#do_not_start_background_activities)

Comment: I had a hunch that it could be the issue, and it indeed was till sometime back. I tried to fix all these issues and checked the logs also that there is no such background activity happening but was still observing this issue.
For now, I have removed global instance for Redis and creating it as and when required (during each operation). I haven't observed the ECONNRESET error for 2-3 days now.

Comment: I am glad to hear that you were able to resolve your issue.